# Docker: create database schema on image build is not working

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Here's what I'm trying to do:

I'm building a simple Flask app connected to SQLite.

I want to create the SQLite database schema during the image build time.

Since SQLite is based on regular files instead of sockets, I need to do some checks to see if the file doesn't exist and so on.

I also want the path to the database file to be set in an enviroment variable, which will be later used by the application to actually run the queries.

My `.env` file:

```
SQLITE_DB_FILE=/data/search_history_new.db
```

My `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine
ARG sqlite_db_file
WORKDIR /app
RUN apk add --no-cache gcc musl-dev linux-headers sqlite
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
RUN ./setup.sh ${sqlite_db_file}
CMD ["flask", "run"]
```

The `setup.sh` file:

```
#!/bin/sh
DB_FILE=${1:-'./.data/search_history.db'}
echo "Checking for the existence of database file: ${DB_FILE}"
if [ ! -f "$DB_FILE" -o ! -s "$DB_FILE" ]; then
  echo "Database not initialized yet..."

  echo "Creating database file..."
  mkdir -p $(dirname "$DB_FILE")
  touch "$DB_FILE"

  echo "Done."
fi

echo "Executing database schema..."
sqlite3 "$DB_FILE" < ./search_history/database/schema.sql

echo "All set."
```

My `schema.sql` file:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXIStS search_history;

CREATE TABLE search_history(
  id VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  created_at INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  full_address TEXT NOT NULL,
  postal_code TEXT NOT NULL,
  country_code TEXT NOT NULL,
  latitude DECIMAL(10,7) NOT NULL,
  longitude DECIMAL(10,7) NOT NULL,
  temperature DECIMAL(6,2)
);

CREATE INDEX idx_postal_code_country_code on
  search_history(postal_code, country_code);

CREATE INDEX idx_created_at on
  search_history(created_at DESC);
```

My `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  server:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
      - sqlite_db_file=${SQLITE_DB_FILE}
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      FLASK_APP: app.py
      FLASK_RUN_HOST: 0.0.0.0
    ports:
    - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
    - ./.data:/app/.data
```

The problem is that during the build time (`docker-compose build`) the database file is not being created, even though the command that creates is being executed.

When I start the server, I notice that the DB file is created, but it's completely empty.

Then of I try to run a query, I get the following error:

```
{
    "message": "no such table: search_history"
}
```

What am I missing?

### Edit

I noticed the following pattern:

- When I run `docker-compose build`, the host `.data` directory is not created.
- When I run `docker-compose run`, the `.data` directory is created with the `search_history.db` file being empty.

### Edit #2

I also noticed that the `.data` directory created is owned by `root`.

If I stop the container and change its owner to my user and start it again, everything works as expected.

Comment: The two things that jump out at me are that the various filesystem paths don't seem to quite line up (is it `/app/.data`, or `/data`, or somewhere else? is there any reason the path _inside_ the container needs to be configurable?), and that you're very likely mounting an empty host directory over the content that get set up during the image build.

Comment: Thank's a lot for commenting, @DavidMaze. You are right, I did so many iterations that ended up being lost on the directories. I'll fix the question. Well, I think the path _inside_ the container don't _need_ to configurable. I am dockerizing this application and it allowed to configure the path for the database. I think the only thing that would need to be configurable is the path on the host.